# How to get the date and title and description alone from this parsing result

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift, nsstring

**How to get the  date and title and description alone from this parsing  result:**

```
title = "Inter-views 29/03/2017 random description here (its in arabic);
title = " \U0627\U062e\U0628\U0627\U0631 \U0627\U0644\U0635\U0628\U0627\U062d 14/04/2017";
```

That's the parsing from same api but different (`didSelectRowAtIndexPath`).
I'm currently using this code but as I notified the parsing is different. So I cannot use static logic.

Code:

```
    NSString *myString = [item objectForKey:@"title"];

    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] 
    initWithArray:[myString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" "]]];

        NSString *Category = @"";
        if(myArray.count>=1){
            Category = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
            [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
        NSString *Date = @"";
        if(myArray.count>=1) {
            Date = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
            [myArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        }
        cell.dateLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [Utils dateTransform:[Date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""] FromFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy" ToFormat:@"dd-MMMM-yyyy"]];
        NSString *Title = @"";
        for (NSString *word in myArray) {
            Title = [Title stringByAppendingString:word];
            Title = [Title stringByAppendingString:@" "];
        }
        cell.titleAndDescLabel.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", Category,Title];
```

Comment: how you get your data? from webservice? can you please give me the response if you get your data from server.

Comment: @DishantRajput THAT THE response but as i said its different from other 
        :    id = 3502;
           image = "";
           isYoutube = 1;
           link = "https://youtu.be/a_AnoV3y1EM";
            title = "Inter-views 29/03/2017 \U0645\U0639 
            \U0623\U0648\U0644 \U0648\U0632\U064a\U0631 
            \U062f\U0
   
            } and thats another response :                                                                  
    id = 3432;
    image = "";
    isYoutube = 1;
    link = "https://youtu.be/bSds01Ew6ns";
    title = "Interviews 22/03/2017";
}

Comment: Please check my answer. I post it. You have to use for loop to get your value one by one. If it works please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Your have to use for loop to get value**

```
for (NSInteger i=0; i<[[jsonObject objectForKey:@"yourMainKey"]count]; i++)
             {

NSString *strname =[[[jsonObject objectForKey:@"yourMainKey"]objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"date"];

                 NSLog(@"strname==%@, strname);


NSString *str title =[[[jsonObject objectForKey:@"yourMainKey"]objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"title"];

                 NSLog(@"strtitle ==%@, strtitle);

NSString *str description =[[[jsonObject objectForKey:@"yourMainKey"]objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"description"];

                 NSLog(@"description ==%@, description);



             }
```